# drupal get path to directory where drupal is installed

Tags: drupal

In the various environments i have, the same Drupal image is not always installed in the root directory.

How can i retrieve the path from `http://` to the directory where the `index.php` file of drupal is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it through

```
global $base_url;
```

[Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7)

Comment: Great to know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it through global variable defined in drupal - $base_url as mentioned by Amol or can directly access it $GLOBALS['base_url'].

And if you need file system path then you can use getcwd().

Answer (score 0):

You can use [base_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) function to get the subfolder or [$GLOBALS['base_path']](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_path/7) variable to get the base path of the Drupal installation.

[More information about the global variables.](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/7)